# CSS3 :not is not excluding an id

Tags: html, css

Hey there dear Stackoverflow Community,

here my css:

```css
.text:not(#overview > *) {
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

i wanted that everything with the class "text" has a margin to the top and bottom of 10px, but not the one marked with the id "overview" and everything under it.
But the css isn´t working as expected.

Thanks for your help
Yasin

Comment: My code is doing the opposite

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isn't working as expected? So it doesn't exclude the `id` itself right? For that you need to add the `id` as well:

```css
.text:not(#overview) {
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

What you are doing now, is just targetting everything inside the `id` and not the `id` itself. This will make sure that the `id` is also targeted.

You can also reset it using:

```css
.text {
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
#overview.text {
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

The `id` has more specificity than class.

[image]

Comment: `.text:not(#overview, #overview > *)` is invalid CSS. The negation pseudo class can only accept a **simple selector**.

Comment: Thanks dude for the fast and good response it worked with the second one

Comment: @Quentin Updated it. Thanks.

Comment: have to wait 2 minutes ^^

Comment: Re update. `.text:not(#overview > *)` — `#overview > *` is not a simple selector. The CSS is still invalid and parsers will ignore it.

Comment: @Quentin Thanks. Check now?

Comment: @Quentin I really don't care about the downvote. I just need my answer to be right. Kindly help. Thanks.

Comment: Now it matches elements without the ID `overview`  but with the class `text`. I'm pretty sure the OP wants to match elements which are not **children** of an element with the id `overview` and with the class `text`

Comment: @Quentin I give up. I said na. I don't know. I provided an alternate solution and it works. `:)`

Answer (score 1):

Well you could do it like this, but not sure if it is the right way!

```css
.text {
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
#overview {
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

Comment: You don't need `!important` here.

Comment: While this might work it explicitly avoids answering the question, which is "*how do I make `:not()` work? as expected?*"

Comment: @PraveenKumar Wasen't sure if it would conflict or not with the .text! I'll edit my answere :)

Comment: @UnScope ids (#overview) are more important that a class (.text), so id style has predominance

Comment: @Pipe Then i learned something today aswell! Will that say that if it was #text and .overview it would need !important?

Comment: @UnScope if you have an element like `<div id="text" class="overview"></div>` the style applied to "#text" will have predominance over the ".overview" style. Check out the image added by @praveen Kumar.